# Is there an order in which Pyomo, pyomo-extras and spyder need to be installed with conda?

Tags: spyder, conda, pyomo

I am trying to set up a conda enviroment with pyomo, numpy/scipy, matplotlib and spyder.

I have tried all possible order permutations of installing pyomo, pyomo-extras and spyder with anaconda and none of the potential options seems to end in a successful install (spyder wont be launch at the end).

Looks to me that the conda dependencies are not very robust, is there a better way to install these three packages that would actually work?

I have observed that spyder installs python37 while pyomo seems to downgrade this to python366.

Thanks, and please be patient with the newbie.
sg

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Please be as explicit as you can about the commands you're using to install all these packages. In particular, I need answers to these questions: What operating system are you using? Are you creating a conda environment to install these packages? Are you using conda or pip to install them? If conda, are you using conda-forge or not? Please re-edit your question and add all that info to it. Also add a step-by-step list of the commands you're using right now.

Comment: Also (as a side note) I understand you're a newbie, but simply saying "I tried to do this and this and it's not working" is really unhelpful. So my recommendation, not just for this time but for your future interactions in StackOverflow, is to be as explicit as possible. (Please don't feel bad about it, my advice will just help you to get the best of this great site).

Comment: FWIW: I've verified that on Mac OS 10.12 the command `conda create -n pyomo python=3.6 conda-forge::pyomo conda-forge::pyomo.extras spyder` successfully installs all mentioned packages and allows launching of spyder in the activated environment (`source activate pyomo` followed by `spyder`). So, to confirm @CarlosCordoba point, we need more details to understand your situation.

Comment: @merv: Thank you for your very helpful (and sermon-free) answer. Certainly it is the willingness to help of the community that makes a great site -like this one-.

Comment: Pyomo is not currently supported on Python 3.7 which might be causing some of the problems. We're hoping to cut a patch release this week to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

At least on Mac OS X, the following installs all the packages you mentioned

```
conda create -n pyomo python=3.6 conda-forge::pyomo conda-forge::pyomo.extras spyder
```

and spyder subsequently launches without issue:

```
source activate pyomo
spyder
```

So, to answer your question, no there isn't any specific order you need to install in.